# Rearranging list of numbers to make a matrix

Tags: text-processing, columns, numeric-data

I am trying to write a script to change the following set of numbers

```
2.659980
3.256998
4.589778
2.120150

2.223365
2.325566
2.121112
3.020111

4.065112
0.221544
1.236665
1.395958
```

to the following form (essentially making a matrix out of a list of numbers which are separated by an empty line)

```
2.659980    2.223365    4.065112
3.256998    2.325566    0.221544
4.589778    2.121112    1.236665
2.120150    3.020111    1.395958
```

Can somebody help how to achieve this.

Comment: `csplit` and `paste` should do it, I would think.  My first thought was `column` but that doesn't *quite* work.

Comment: If you know the number of columns, then maybe something as simple as `pr -t -3 file`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With *BSD's `rs(1)`, assuming the input file is well-formed:

```
rs -C -t $( awk '/^$/ { print NR-1; exit }' file ) <file
```

Comment: It works. If you could explain how it works then it will be more useful.

Comment: @ankit7540 The `awk` command prints the number of lines till the first blank line.  That's pretty much all there is to it, the `rs(1)` options are described in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

A pure awk approach

```
awk '{a[NR%5]=a[NR%5] $0 " "}END{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}' file
```